# Is the Lamb shift big or small?

Tags: atomic-physics, spectroscopy

The shift is about 1000 MHz. Is this a significant number by the standard of modern spectroscopy? I mean, is it fairly easy to detect this shift nowadays? It might be difficult in 1947.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the Lamb shift was first found experimentally by Willis Lamb in 1947. Bethe managed to explain it afterwards and it is said that he did so on the train ride after attending a conference where the Lamb shift was presented.

They had to be ingenious about it, but they succeeded. You can find info about this in the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamb_shift).